# iOS Firebase Auth Domain visible to users

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have searched for solutions to this issue but everything I've found seems to be applicable to a firebase web app, not to iOS implementations.

When verifying a user using firebase phone auth for iOS, I understand the recaptacha is very unlikely to appear. However in the event it does, it creates a webview for the recaptcha like so:

[image]

Is there any way for me to hide the `myProjectId-12345.firebaseapp.com` from the user? It's not very clean or secure I'm afraid. I haven't been able to find anything in the way of documentation on this topic, and most stack overflow answers that solved the issue seem to be applicable to the firebase web sdk only.

Am I missing it somewhere? I have followed the documentation for silent notifications as well, so normally the recaptcha does not appear. From the documentation, "only a very small percentage of users will experience the recaptcha", but I would still like to account for those users.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am in the same situation and looking for solution. Please post your answer if you found a solution. That will be very helpful. I connected my custom domain to firebase but not able to figure out how to show it to users instead of default url.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't able to figure it out. I ended up dropping phone auth in favor of custom auth tokens from Firebase Auth (due to application requirements changing, but this issue definitely didn't help)

Comment: Thanks for responding to me. I was not able to figure out how to solve this and got stuck. Also not sure if it secure to show the default url to end users.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your domain for Hosting

**Step 1: Add domain**

- From your project's Hosting page, enter the wizard for connecting a
  custom domain:
- If you have only one Hosting site, click Connect domain. If you have
  more than one Hosting site, click View for the desired site, then
  click Connect domain. Enter the custom domain name that you'd like to
  connect to your Hosting site.
- (Optional) Check the box to redirect all requests on the custom
  domain to a second specified domain (such that example.com and
  [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) redirect to the same content).
- Click Continue to initiate the validation process.

**Step 2: Verify domain ownership**

If requested in the Connect Domain setup wizard, verify your apex domain.

**Step 3: Go live**

- In the Connect Domain window of the Firebase console, select Quick
  Setup for a new site or Advanced Setup if you already have a site
  running on another hosting provider and need a zero-downtime
  migration.

Have a look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) for detailed information.

Comment: I've got one set up already, but it seems the auth domain can only be specified in the firebase app configuration for the web sdk. ```FirebaseApp.configure()``` from the iOS sdk doesn't seem to give that same option

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu Made the changes.