# App being rejected due as project name contains the word "android"

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

We had started our app development in android, due to which the team named our firebase project as "xyz-corp-android" and published the app, which was a mistake.

Now, after some time we started with our iOS app, but while publishing the app rejects our submission as the captcha screen contains the word android in it (in the url).

We cant find a way to changes the firebase project id.
what can be done in this case?

[rejection reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo5zc.png)
[screenshot of the word android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJPMg.png)

Comment: create the another key without name of ios/andriod and submit ur project

Comment: Setup a call with Apple and explain it's just a URL to your captcha. But you really don't want to expose your firebase URLs direct to users. You should consider hiding the url from the captcha page.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394847/ios-firebase-auth-domain-visible-to-users